# 100% height div

Tags: html, css, height

I have a `#main` div that I'd like to fill the page between the header and footer when there is no content.  When there is content, it should push the sticky footer down, which it does.

CSS:

```
#main {
 background: transparent url("images/main-content.png") top right repeat-y;
 clear: both;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: -10px;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
}
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working.  `#main` inherits from `#wrapper` and `body`, so I'd think setting up 100% height and min-height of 100% would work.

Site:

http://www.dentistrywithsmiles.com

Thanks in advance for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's that `height: auto !important;` somewhere near line `146` of your CSS file.

It's overriding the 100% height of your wrapper, which isn't letting your main div grow. Since your footer has a constant height, I would try adding a padding to the wrapper to make the main content div not eat into the footer, which is what happens when you turn of the `height: auto !important;`.

Comment: Thanks @Blender - can you give an example of the padding you would add?  If I add padding to the bottom of `#wrapper`, it just pushes my footer down, and I'd like it to remain sticky.

Comment: Sorry, I have a lot to do, so maybe later I might whip something up. If your content `div` is to assume a height which fills up the page and doesn't let the footer crawl above the page height, why settle with a sticky footer? You could just specify a minimum height for that div and you'd be set, as it already pushes that footer `div` down. just thinking...

Comment: It might not be totally necessary, but I'd like to keep the sticky footer so that if the page doesn't have much content the content `div` meets the footer no matter what screen resolution and browser.  It's kind of important to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to `#main` (or to `#wrapper`, depending on what you want to do). Items with `display:block` (such as a div or p tag by default) have 100% width and height that adjusts to the content.